# Change column delims for a range of columns using bash

Tags: awk, sed

I have an table with multiple columns and I would like to skip the first and second column.  Then I would like to change the delimiter for the (n + 2 columns) from tab to comma.  Any suggestions with awk or sed with be helpful definitely, because normally I could just a find and replace(with sed) but I keep replacing the tabs in the first two columns.

An example test set:

```
M1  D.130   a   a   a
M2  D.104   -   a   ab
M3  D.150   ab  ab  a
M4  D.160   a   a   -
M5  D.107   a   ab  a
M6  D.107   -   ab  -
M7  D.104   a   ab  ab
```

Desired Output:

```
M1  D.130   a,a,a
M2  D.104   -,a,ab
M3  D.150   ab,ab,a
M4  D.160   a,a,-
M5  D.107   a,ab,a
M6  D.107   -,ab,-
M7  D.104   a,ab,ab
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For given input, you can simply use below

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3 "," $4 "," $5}' infile
```

Or else

```
awk -v n=3 '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:i<n?OFS:",")}' infile
```

**With `gawk` to retain original spacing:**

```
awk -v n=3 '{
              split($0,t,FS,d);
              for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:i<n?d[i]:",")
            }' infile
```

**non-gawk to retain original spacing:**

```
awk -v n=3 '{
              split($0,d,/[^[:space:]]*/);
              for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                 printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:i<n?d[i+1]:",")
            }' infile
```

**For Example :**

```
$ cat infile
M1  D.130   a   a   a
M2  D.104   -   a   ab
M3  D.150   ab  ab  a
M4  D.160   a   a   -
M5  D.107   a   ab  a
M6  D.107   -   ab  -
M7  D.104   a   ab  ab

$ awk -v n=3 '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:i<n?OFS:",")}' file
M1 D.130 a,a,a
M2 D.104 -,a,ab
M3 D.150 ab,ab,a
M4 D.160 a,a,-
M5 D.107 a,ab,a
M6 D.107 -,ab,-
M7 D.104 a,ab,ab
```

**With `Gawk` to retain original spacing**

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{split($0,t,FS,d);for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:i<n?d[i]:",")}' infile
M1  D.130   a,a,a
M2  D.104   -,a,ab
M3  D.150   ab,ab,a
M4  D.160   a,a,-
M5  D.107   a,ab,a
M6  D.107   -,ab,-
M7  D.104   a,ab,ab
```

**With `non-Gawk` to retain original spacing**

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{split($0,d,/[^[:space:]]*/);for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:i<n?d[i+1]:",")}' infile
M1  D.130   a,a,a
M2  D.104   -,a,ab
M3  D.150   ab,ab,a
M4  D.160   a,a,-
M5  D.107   a,ab,a
M6  D.107   -,ab,-
M7  D.104   a,ab,ab
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(([^\t]+\t){2})(.*)/,a) {gsub(/\t/,",",a[3]); print a[1] a[3]}' file
M1      D.130   a,a,a
M2      D.104   -,a,ab
M3      D.150   ab,ab,a
M4      D.160   a,a,-
M5      D.107   a,ab,a
M6      D.107   -,ab,-
M7      D.104   a,ab,ab
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([^\t]+\t){2}/) {r=substr($0,RLENGTH+1); gsub(/\t/,",",r); print substr($0,1,RLENGTH) r}' file
M1      D.130    a,a,a
M2      D.104    -,a,ab
M3      D.150    ab,ab,a
M4      D.160    a,a,-
M5      D.107    a,ab,a
M6      D.107    -,ab,-
M7      D.104    a,ab,ab
```

Comment: Very nice way of using regexp

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command :

```
$ awk '{for(i=3; i<NF; i++){a=a$i","} {OFS="  "; print $1,$2,a$NF} a=""}' file
M1  D.130  a,a,a
M2  D.104  -,a,ab
M3  D.150  ab,ab,a
M4  D.160  a,a,-
M5  D.107  a,ab,a
M6  D.107  -,ab,-
M7  D.104  a,ab,ab
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple **awk** approach:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ r=$1 FS $2 FS $3; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) r=r","$i; print r }' file
```

The output:

```
M1  D.130   a,a,a
M2  D.104   -,a,ab
M3  D.150   ab,ab,a
M4  D.160   a,a,-
M5  D.107   a,ab,a
M6  D.107   -,ab,-
M7  D.104   a,ab,ab
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed 's/\t/,/3;s/\t/,/3' file
```